# Como armazenar palavras de um texto em um array

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso criar uma função que pegue um texto e armazene cada palavra em um array. Em c# eu sei que existe a função ToCharArray() e com isso eu só preciso fazer um "for" para e verificar quando existe um espaço em branco, mas como faço isso em js?

Comment: Para criar um array com palavras basta fazer `texto.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função **split**

Se precisa separar palavras, passe como parâmetro o separados desejado:

```js
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';

var arrayDePalavras = text.split(' ');
// note que estou usando um espaço em branco. Poderia ser qualquer outro caracter, como um hífen, por exemplo. Ou até mesmo uma palavra.

console.log(arrayDePalavras );
```

E se precisar de um efeito semelhante ao ToCharArray do C#, passe como parâmetro uma string vazia:

```js
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
var arrayDeCaracteres = text.split('');
console.log(arrayDeCaracteres);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a função .split e atribua a frase em um array

```js
function guarda_palavra(){
       
      text = document.getElementById('texto').value; 
      var arr = text.split(" ");
      
      alert('array com a frase escrita: '+arr);

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='texto' placeholder='digite a frase'>
<button onclick="guarda_palavra('minha frase')">click </button>
```